# Получить путь к программе, имея ее handle

Tags: c#

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Через FindWindow() получаю хандл **чужого** окна, нужно узнать, из какой папки это окно запущено.

Comment: Вы путаете дескриптор окна и дескриптор файла.

Comment: Я еще очень слабо разобрался в этой теме. Тогда поставим вопрос подргугому :) 
Есть хандл, дескриптор файла можно получить? И уже из него, как я понял, получить путь к самому файлу.

Comment: @lexanom, что такое путь к запущенному окну? А если приложение без окна?
Вам нужно реализовать именно через winapi или главное узнать путь к исполнительному файлу процесса?

Comment: @pincher1519, ну как без окна, если его хандл я уже получил? :) приложение запущено, окно открыто, из своего приложения я могу посылать в это окно команды и нажатия клавиш. Но теперь понадобилось узнать откуда приложение запущено, чтобы прочитать некоторые его конфиги...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, вам поможет вот что:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

public static string GetFullName(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);

    return Process.GetProcessById((int) pid).MainModule.FileName;
}
```

З.Ы. Не забудьте в свойствах проекта установить platform target в значение x64, в противном случае получите исключение при обращении к 64-битным приложениям

З.З.Ы. Немного поправил ответ для получения пути по хэндлу окна. Также не забудьте сделать проверки на null внутри GetFullName